# getting javascript Audio component to reload

Tags: javascript, audio, vuejs2

I am using vue and electron for an app that, among other things, plays audio. The app uses the standard 'Audio' constructor to play the first clip. Then the app rewrites the audio and tries to play the new audio (with the old name) again. Right now the old audio plays even after the new track has been saved.

How do I force the Audio component to reload the track?

```
    const audio = new Audio(require("../sample.mp3"));
    audio.play();
```

Thanks. Any help would be appreciated. I actually use a 'ended' callback which is not shown in the code snippet.

Comment: Does it reload the track when you refresh the page? If not, it would seem that the file gets cached.

Comment: I think it is cached. How do I load a file after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not have control over how the browser manages the cache.
This can be regulated by using cache headers that are sent by the server to instruct the browser how to manage the cache.

That aside, a common way to solve caching (as often done by bundlers) is to generate a new filename with unique hash for every version of the file.
This way you don't have to worry about cached files.

Comment: I have edited my code some. I am now trying to use a scheme like this. Now I get: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found."

Comment: I assume the reason is because it can't find the file in the location you specified...

Comment: I'm wondering if electron or vue.js is prohibiting me from loading an mp3.

Comment: I'm also wondering if I should put the mp3 in the 'dist' folder.

Comment: I  set `filenameHashing: false` in the 'vue.config.js' file and then tried to load my file. The error message changed to 'net::ERR_FAILED'. I still cannot load my mp3.

Comment: I'm sorry friend. It seems to me that the path parameter you add to the constructor is the file location. Either this would be a url, but in case of a relative path I would assume this to be delivered along with the bundle in the relative path. So you need to check why the file isn't bundled in the way you expect, or run a webserver from which you deliver the file.